# Why is this client-server system not working (simple)

Tags: python, python-2.7, server, client, client-server

I am trying to make a very simple client-system simple and I am not sure what is wrong with it. It is supposed to be a calculator system. Here is the code for the client:

```
import socket

IP = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 8106

my_socket = socket.socket()
my_socket.connect((IP, PORT))


done = False

while not done:
    command = raw_input("choose a command from [ADD, SUB, MUL, DIV, EXIT]")
    command = command.upper()
    my_socket.send(command)
    data = my_socket.recv(20)
    new_list = data.split(":")
    if command in ["ADD", "SUB", "MUL", "DIV", "EXIT"]:
        if command == "ADD":
            print new_list[0] + "+" + new_list[1] + "=" + new_list[2]
        if command == "SUB":
            print new_list[0] + "-" + new_list[1] + "=" + new_list[2]
        if command == "MUL":
            print new_list[0] + "*" + new_list[1] + "=" + new_list[2]
        if command == "DIV":
            print new_list[0] + "/" + new_list[1] + "=" + new_list[2]
        if command == "EXIT":
            done = True
    else:
        print 'not valid'
```

and here is the code of the server:

```
import socket
import random

IP = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 8106

server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind((IP, PORT))

server_socket.listen(1)

(client_socket, client_address) = server_socket.accept()


done = False

while not done:
    message = client_socket.recv(4)
    num1 = random.randint(-101, 100)
    print num1
    num2 = random.randint(-101, 100)
    print num2
    if message in ["ADD", "SUB", "MUL", "DIV", "EXIT"]:
        if message == "ADD":
            result = num1 + num2
        elif message == "SUB":
            result = num1 - num2
        elif message == "MUL":
            result = num1 * num2
        elif message == "DIV":
            result = float(num1) / float(num2)
        elif message == "EXIT":
            done = True
        client_socket.send(str(num1) + ":" + str(num2) + ":" + str(result))
    else:
        client_socket.send("0:0:0")
```

Now, when I run the server and then the client, and choose "DIV" for a couple of times, the first time also works, but at the second or the third try I get an error message:

```
print new_list[0] + "/" + new_list[1] + "=" + new_list[2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am not sure why it is happening. I tried to print "data" to try to solve it, and sometimes the data is just one number, for example just 46, instead of something like 46:3:15.333

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

The docs for the [socket.recv(bufsize[, flags])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv) method specify the following:

> The maximum amount of data to be received at once is specified by bufsize.

The key part is that `bufsize` is the *maximum* number of bytes you may receive from a single call, so the individual byte strings you receive may not be exactly the same, in number and size, as the ones you called `send` with on the other side.

The only thing which *is* guaranteed for a socket created with the default type (`SOCK_STREAM` i.e. TCP) is that your stream of bytes will arrive in the same order as they were sent.

You will therefore have to design a protocol which allows both the client and server to identify the boundaries of each individual message.

Here are a couple of ways you could achieve that:

1. Include information about the length of each message in the message itself. For example, the first byte of each message could be an integer which gives the length of the rest of the message, giving a maximum message size of 255 (excluding the length prefix).
2. Make every message the same size. That way you don't have to encode the length in the message - you can just keep calling `recv` until you have the expected number of bytes. You would have to ensure that you can express each number in the same format and length, though.

Edit: as per [kirill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58575064/12279479), you will also have to fix your code for sending the data (by using `sendall` for example). It's not possible to say which of these problems is causing your issue without further information, though.

Answer (score 0):

`socket.send` doesn't guaranty sanding of complete data. Your application should check how many bytes were send base on `socket.send` return value.

Alternatively just use `socket.sendall` and check for exceptions like that:

```py
try:
    s.sendall(MESSAGE)
except socket.error:
    # failed to send
```

See `socket.send` and `socket.sendall` in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html).